# Which size of png for background I shall use for a device with screen 1280*720 / xhdpi

Tags: android

Screen resolution 1280 * 720 / xhdpi (Example: Sony Lt26i / Galaxy Nexus)

Which size of png/jpg for background(fill the whole screen without distortion) I shall use for the device (res/drawable-xhdpi), 1280px * 720px or 2560px * 1440px?

In this case, I always use 2560px * 1440px till I find some APPs use 1280px * 720px........
I believe double pixels shall be used on xhdpi screen.

Thanks a lot! ^_^

Comment: Refer to android documentation http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Answer (score 1):

The exact size is: 1280x720 **pixel**.
When you hear about *double pixels* you are actually speaking about DIP, Density Independent Pixel.
A device which has a screen size of 1280x720 *pixels*, and has a *XHDPI* screen, will result in a 640x360 **dp**.

Android will take care of scaling and adapting the size for you, if needed.

Maybe it is a good idea to spend half an hour to read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Android SDK document：
"The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160)"

So if dp = 1280, dpi = 320, then px = 1280 * 320 / 160 = 2560pixel

Comment: Do I make it reversal?
The correct is : The width (or height) of picture is 1280pixel, and dp is 640 on a device with resolution 1280*720 xhdpi.
Am I right at this point now?

Thanks

Comment: The concept is simple: you should think in DPs.
Devices scale automatically to adapt to their actual resolution, and take the png/jpg resources from the correct drawable folder.
To adapt to all devices, and to provide the correct resources for your app, you should produce the same image at 1280x720 for xhdpi, 640x360 for mdpi, 960x540 for hdpi and 480x270 for ldpi, and place files in the correct folders.
Take a look to the link in my post answer for correct folder naming, and to find more details about customization